# Disable Android SurfaceView move animation

Tags: android, android-layout

I am moving a SurfaceView containing a video by using `view.setLayoutParams(...)`. When the view moves to it's new location there seems to be an animation which smoothly 'slides' the video from it's original location to the new one. What I want is for the SurfaceView simply to disappear from the original location and appear at the new one.

I looked in the SurfaceView source and found the following line in the `updateWindow()` method:

```
mLayout.privateFlags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.PRIVATE_FLAG_NO_MOVE_ANIMATION;
```

This looks like it might be relevant, but I'm not sure.

Is it possible to disable this animation?

Comment: any news on this one?

Comment: No, I gave up trying to fix this, and stopped trying to reuse the same SurfaceView. I now just create a new SurfaceView each time.

Comment: So the user sees a flicker when you create the new surface and destroy the old one?

Comment: IIRC, in Android 2.3, the SurfaceView flickers (flashes white) when a new view is attached, so I initially size it to 1x1, then resize when the SurfaceView is ready. In Android 4+ I don't see the flicker.